# jQuery bounce() queues requests

Tags: jquery, bounce

I've got a problem with by jQuery ui bounce() effect. If I move the mouse back and forth the picture a lot of times, it queues the requests and keeps bouncing the exact same times I've hovered the image.

I've searched the questions and found a solution to check if this.animated. But it didn't work either. Here's my current js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('#admin_".$id."').mouseover(function () { if (!$(this).is(':animated')) $(this).effect('bounce', { times:1 }, 300); }); });
```

Comment: Care to set up a jsfiddle.net example for us?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Silvar/AYTdL/ - Here you go | The bounce effect doesn't stop in IE either. It keeps bouncing even though it's set to times:1

Comment: Okay, the first problem I've encountered isn't showing up on jsfiddle. It does not queue the bounces, but it does on my website. That is pretty strange. But anyway, how to make it only bounce one time in IE?

Comment: The jsfiddle doesn't have any code in it?

Comment: How come? I'm not familiar with jsfiddle. First time using it. I've typed in both the css, html and javascript and also linked to the js query ui file.

Comment: I'm not sure, it appears that you were logged in on there or something, maybe if you log in it doesn't show your code? I don't know. But what if you try changing `if (!$(this).is(':animated'))` to `if ($(this).not(':animated'))

Comment: Didn't work. Both Chrome and IE keeps queuing each time i hover so it keeps bouncing, and IE won't stop the bouncing when constantly hovering.

Comment: When using is(':animated') as first written, I fixed the problem with the queueing. The only problem is, that IE keeps bouncing then element when the mouse is hovering. Really can't seem to figure out this problem.

Comment: In the jsfiddle you posted above it continued to bounce and bounce, (firefox)

Comment: Don't got Firefox atm. but on my website it only keeps bouncing in IE, not Chrome. I've done a lot of research and it seems like a lot of people got problems with the bounce effect not stopping.

Comment: Just installed Firefox. Both Firefox and IE keeps bouncing, but Chrome doesn't. One more reason to love Chrome.